# C99 - guarantees about ordering of floating-point rounding modes

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer, c99, floating-accuracy

Are there any guarantees (in the C99 standard and/or IEEE-754) that the results obtained when using different rounding modes should be ordered in a particular way?

For instance, let `f(rm, x)` be a function where `rm` is the rounding mode and `x` its argument. Can I consider that a bug-free implementation should ensure the following inequality?

```
f(FE_DOWNWARD,x) <= f(FE_TONEAREST,x) <= f(FE_UPWARD,x)
```

As an example, the following code on my machine contradicts this hypothesis (even using a recent glibc, version 2.21), and I wonder if it's a bug (worth reporting), or simply an unfortunate consequence of rounding errors, which means that such behavior should never be relied upon.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

void set_round(int rm) {
  // checks that the rounding mode has been successfully set
  if (fesetround(rm)) { perror("setround"); exit(1); }
}

int main() {
  printf("GNU libc version: %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());
  float x = 3;
  set_round(FE_TONEAREST);
  float r = log10f(x);
  printf("nearest:     r = %g (%a)\n", r, r);

  set_round(FE_DOWNWARD);
  r = log10f(x);
  printf("downward:    r = %g (%a)\n", r, r);

  set_round(FE_UPWARD);
  r = log10f(x);
  printf("upward:      r = %g (%a)\n", r, r);

  set_round(FE_TOWARDZERO);
  r = log10f(x);
  printf("toward zero: r = %g (%a)\n", r, r);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
GNU libc version: 2.21
nearest:     r = 0.477121 (0x1.e89278p-2)
downward:    r = 0.477121 (0x1.e8927ap-2)
upward:      r = 0.477122 (0x1.e8927cp-2)
toward zero: r = 0.477121 (0x1.e8927ap-2)
```

**Edit**: it turns out this specific example is a GCC "feature"<sup>1</sup>: using Clang, or activating GCC's optimization flags, or using a literal constant instead of the variable when calling `log10f`, all of them result in consistent values. The question still stands in the general case, however.

<sup>1</sup> This is not considered a bug by GCC, but rather a surprising result due to optimizations performed directly by GCC without involving an imprecise glibc.

Comment: Why C99 specifically?  Why not "C" or "C11"?

Comment: Mainly because C99 introduces the `FE_*` rounding modes in `fenv.h`, but you're right that the question is not C99-specific *per se*.

Comment: Your example program calls functions from fenv.h but it doesn't contain `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`. This means that the compiler is allowed to do as it pleases. However, if you add this pragma, GCC will tell you that it doesn't support it. As far as I remember it doesn't tell you in the warning message that it supports a file-wise equivalent of this pragma on the commandline, but it does support such a commandline flag, `-frounding-math`, and if you are lucky you will not find a bug in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such guarantee is made.

Some math libraries attempt to satisfy this constraint *for math library functions only*, but that behavior is not required by any standard, and it is quite rare (even most libraries that attempt to provide it have compromises and bugs).

For functions that are not in the math library, attempting to conform to that property would be nearly impossible, mostly useless anyway, and so is essentially unheard of.

IEEE-754 (2008) *recommends*, but does not require, that a specific subset of the math library functions be correctly rounded (or that correctly-rounded versions be made available), which implies the property you're looking for.  This recommendation is not widely implemented at present, however.

Comment: Does any version of the C Standard specify anything about the *sequencing* of floating-point mode changes with regard to computation?  By my understanding, given `double x=1/w+foo(); double y=1/w+bar(); double z=1/w+boz();` a compiler would be entitled to optimize `1/w` as a common subexpression even if it knew nothing about `bar`.  If `bar` changes floating-point modes, what guarantee would there be that the change would take effect before computing the (1/w) term of `z`?  Unless an implementation offers guarantees beyond those in the standard, would rounding modes be reliably relevant?